# K8s: why the service endpoints is <none> i.e. empty?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service

- using Docker Desktop and running the built-in Kubernetes
  [image]
- deployed hello app and a load-balancer service
- you can see the output of `kk get all -o wide` //kk short for kubectl
- also see output of

  - `kk get nodes`
  - `kk describe service hello-service`
  - `kk describe deployment`
- you can also see output of `kk get endpoints`

  - `hello-service   <none>`

[image]

- finally you can see the output of `curl localhost:8080`

  - `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`

**I think the reason for `Empty reply from server` is because the endpoints is `<none>`. Any idea why the endpoints is empty? and how I can fix this?**

Answer (score 2):

- turns out the service selector was bad it is `app=helloapp` but should be `name=helloapp`

[image]

- with correct selector

[image]