# Why is the service endpoint empty? Is it a bug in the official tutorial?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service

I am trying to learn k8s and following along in the official tutorials
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/expose/expose-interactive/

Why is the endpoint empty? The tutorial says that

> We have now a running Service called kubernetes-bootcamp. Here we see
> that the Service received a unique cluster-IP, an internal port and an
> **external-IP (the IP of the Node)**

I only see `<none>` . This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71469387/k8s-why-the-service-endpoints-is-none-i-e-empty) says it should be `name`, not `app`, should it be `name` instead of `app`?

```
$ kubectl expose deployment/kubernetes-bootcamp --type="NodePort" --port 8080
service/kubernetes-bootcamp exposed

$ kubectl get services
NAME                  TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes            ClusterIP   10.96.0.1      <none>        443/TCP          9m13s
kubernetes-bootcamp   NodePort    10.101.46.87   <none>        8080:30568/TCP   7m49s

$ kubectl describe services/kubernetes-bootcamp
Name:                     kubernetes-bootcamp
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   app=kubernetes-bootcamp
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=kubernetes-bootcamp
Type:                     NodePort
IP Families:              <none>
IP:                       10.101.46.87
IPs:                      10.101.46.87
Port:                     <unset>  8080/TCP
TargetPort:               8080/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  30568/TCP
Endpoints:                172.18.0.4:8080
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>


$ kubectl get services
NAME                  TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes            ClusterIP   10.96.0.1      <none>        443/TCP          9m13s
kubernetes-bootcamp   NodePort    10.101.46.87   <none>        8080:30568/TCP   7m49s
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"External-IP is `<none>` when there is no load balancer" (Sander Van Vugt)

Answer (score 0):

It's correct that you don't see EXTERNAL-IP if you use a service of type NodePort.

"If you set the type field to NodePort, the Kubernetes control plane allocates a port from a range specified by --service-node-port-range flag (default: 30000-32767). **Each node proxies that port** (the same port number on every Node) into your Service."
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-nodeport

Take a look at this example:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/service-access-application-cluster/

Comment: I am asking why the _ip address_ is `<none>` It appears you are answering about the _port_